# Is this chart of the mesorah of Torah available in English?

Tags: product-recommendation, translation, mesorah-tradition, english

Does anyone know if [this chart](http://shesileizeisim.blogspot.com/2011/12/poster-of-mesorah-of-oral-torah.html?m=1) of the mesora of Torah is available in English? or if there is anything like it in English?

[image: Merkos Mesorah Chart]

Comment: Paging @LazerA.

Comment: Seems like someone one could easily just edit in photoshop and translate into English.

Comment: [From R' Goldstein. These guys are pretty important.](https://ibb.co/RC6MmWD)

Answer (score 16):

My sister made this chart. It is kind of a condensed version of the hebrew one:

[image: English Torah Mesorah Chart]

And here's a version with the titles transliterated, instead of translated:

[image: Transliterated Torah Mesorah Chart]

Comment: Did you not put the links there on purpose?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin: There are no links. She sent it to me and I posted it here. It was originally a pdf, but I converted it to jpg

Comment: Thanks for sharing this Mesora chart, it is most helpful!

Comment: Menachem, by "links" I think Shmuel meant the connecting lines.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: If so, it was just technical limitations of the program she was using (or perhaps lack of knowledge of how to do it in the program).

Comment: As beautiful as this is, I think the missing connecting lines misrepresent the original chart. Based on the original, Zohar and Medrashim are hanging off Tanach, but aren't necessarily a path from there to shisha sidrei mishna. Without the connectors, it seems they are an integral path that connects shisha sidrei mishna to Tanach.

Answer (score 5):

There's a multi-colored [one on chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2129/jewish/The-Torah-from-Sinai-A-Diagram.htm), the title of the article is "The Torah from Sinai - A Diagram".

[image: The content in this page is produced by Chabad.org, and is copyrighted by the author and/or Chabad.org. If you enjoyed this article, we encourage you to distribute it further, provided that you do not revise any part of it, and you include this note, credit the author, and link to www.chabad.org. If you wish to republish this article in a periodical, book, or website, please email permissions@chabad.org.]

<sup>The content in this page is produced by Chabad.org, and is copyrighted by the author and/or Chabad.org. If you enjoyed this article, we encourage you to distribute it further, provided that you do not revise any part of it, and you include this note, credit the author, and link to www.chabad.org. If you wish to republish this article in a periodical, book, or website, please email permissions@chabad.org.</sup>

Comment: Note how the Chabad one that you linked to has the Zohar feeding into the Medrash, as opposed to the one the OP posted.